# Extends must include one of union

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Given:

```
export type MapToInput<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends firestore.Timestamp | undefined | null
    ? firestore.Timestamp | Date
    : T[K];
};
```

When:

```
interface Boop {
  a: undefined;
}

type x = MapToInput<Boop>;
```

I would like:

`x.a` not to be `firestore.Timestamp | Date`. Is there a way to say in the type above that

I want to match:

- `firestore.Timestamp` or
- `firestore.Timestamp | undefined` or
- `firestore.Timestamp | null` or
- `firestore.Timestamp | undefined | null`

But not:

- `undefined` or
- `undefened | null` or
- `null`

fine:

```
interface Beep {
  a: firestore.Timestamp;
}

type y = MapToInput<Beep>;
```

fine:

```
interface Blab {
  a?: firestore.Timestamp;
}

type z = MapToInput<Blab>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the intend of the type correctly it's to add `Date` if the `firestore.Timestamp` is already present in the property type.

I think the cleanest solution would be to use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to add the extra constituent of the union. With a distributive conditional type we can consider each constituent of the union and add `Date` if it is `Timestamp` or leave it unchanged if it is not. Like this, we can avoid the problem of `null` and `undefined` combinations altogether:

```
export type AddTimeStamp<T> = T extends firestore.Timestamp?
           firestore.Timestamp | Date:
           T;
export type MapToInput<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: AddTimeStamp<T[K]>;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=37&pln=15&pc=41#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAzAlgJ2gFwPZaQG8BYAKCQqQgA8Z9sk1hsIMUFkAVNSKbcGESTYeOAQC5hGAK4QAvmQWkyNOhgbYAnjGQBBACb7ukAMr8wMADycAfEgC8STlWotg+qKkw58EAHTGYhYA-F5YfL4BonwCSAA+SAAiICySnADcKrT0wtrIALIgMJy4AJLAMNLY1naOJOSUANoA0ozASADWEJq4KE4AupIGRqJmAtYt-TaZpHIzZEwsbBxIAEK4uIL1lEjAuB0AjJLS7hDowBD6Mzt7HQBMx6fnl-G70gA279eUtwDMksAPu8yDt9kcwj4sFFeOZBCDKPsHhCIlDAjELK8TvozkwXvCKPt-si8KjorDXoDPkh8Uh9gAWSTocIk-xo8kJLE4i76ClAxRkMhaHRIagOJCFYplCpVSzrTbTIA)

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why it's different when `T extends firestore.Timestamp ? firestore.Timestamp | Date: T;` is in a separate type vs being in `MapToInput` Is that because when it's in a separate type it becomes this "distributive conditional type` and when it's inline it's not?

Comment: @albertjan exactly. For distribution to happen, you need the condition to be over a naked type parameter. So `T extends Timestamp` is distributive, `T[K] extends Timestamp` is not. `T[K] extends infer U ? U extends TimeStamp? ....` would also be distributive over `U` but is hard to read so I generally avoid it

Answer (score 0):

Exclude your unwanted types and check for never. This will result in your desired behaviour

```
interface Timestamp {
    [val]: typeof val
}

export type MapToInput<T> = {
    [K in keyof T 
      as [Exclude<T[K], undefined | null>] extends [never] ? never : K]:  
     T[K]
};

interface Boop {
    a: undefined;
    b: Timestamp,
    c: Timestamp | undefined,
    d: Timestamp | null,
    e: Timestamp | undefined | null
    f: undefined | null
    g: null
}

type x = MapToInput<Boop>;
```

Comment: Good attempt but I did want to keep the `undefined | null` when they were in the original type.

Comment: I updated my answer. Here if you don't want to keep the properties

Comment: Have a look at the answer from @Titian. I appreciate my question wasn't worded very nicely. ☺️